# Why does formatting a NSPredicate while encoding URL cause a crash in swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, swift, nspredicate

Recently, I try to use NSpredicate for phone number validate in a swift project, but it always crashes.
The code is like this:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    var regexPhoneNum = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", "^1[0-9]{10}$")
    println(regexPhoneNum)
    return true
}
```

It crashes at

```
var regexPhoneNum = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", "^1[0-9]{10}$")
```

Crash info:

```
2015-09-08 09:51:17.044 PredicateTest[4319:79934] -[__NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7c153110
```

I find that crash caused by a NSString category which used Objective-C, codes as below:

`.h`

```
@interface NSString (HttpManager)
- (NSString *)encode;
@end
```

`.m`

```
@implementation NSString (HttpManager)
- (NSString *)encode
{
NSString *outputString  = (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,
(CFStringRef)self,
NULL,
(CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&amp;=+$,/?%#[]",
kCFStringEncodingUTF8
));
outputString = [outputString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<null>" withString:@""];
return outputString;
}
@end
```

Anyone who can solve this problem or give me some suggestions, Thanks!

Comment: in my case it is not crashing tested on xcode 7 beta 5

Comment: I also cannot reproduce the issue with Xcode 6.4. Is that your exact code? – The error message indicates that you have a NSString somewhere where an NSArray is expected.

Comment: well,I creat a new project and paste the line of code in the function of 'application   didFinishLaunching'  also runs correctly.  It's my exact code, thank you

Comment: sorry, I find the crash caused by a NSString category, but why?

Answer (score 0):

get it! Probably NSPredicate format a string use a encode method by default! The category's encode conflict to system's...
omg, friends be careful about this situation. I just change the method name by add a prefix and solve the problem!!!